# Trigger MySQL não identifica campos

Tags: mysqli

boa noite,

Possuo uma trigger no MySQL, mas que não funciona, ela apenas chama uma procedure passando um valor. Não gera erro, mas não funciona.

código da trigger:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger trg_hardware_ai after insert on hardware
for each row
begin
    #call criar_setores(new.id);
    insert into setor (nome, defasados, atualizados, total) values ('ALAN01', 0, 1, 1);
end $$
delimiter;
```

código da procedure:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE criar_setores(id_hardware int)
BEGIN
    declare nome_setor varchar(50);
    declare defasados_setor, atualizados_setor, memoria, existe_setor int;
    
    select name, memory into nome_setor, memoria from hardware where id = id_hardware;
    select substring(nome_setor, 1, 6) into nome_setor;
    
    if ((memoria / 4000) >= 1) then
        set defasados_setor = 0;
        set atualizados_setor = 1;
    else
        set defasados_setor = 1;
        set atualizados_setor = 0;
    end if;
    
    select id into existe_setor from setor where nome = nome_setor;

    if (existe_setor is not null) then
        update setor set 
            defasados = defasados + defasados_setor, 
            atualizados = atualizados + atualizados_setor,
            total = total + 1
            where nome = nome_setor;
    else    
        insert into setor (nome, defasados, atualizados, total) 
            values (nome_setor, defasados_setor, atualizados_setor, 1);
    end if;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

se eu chamar a procedure diretamente ela funciona:

`call criar_setores(14);`

É como se a trigger não reconhecesse o campo new.id

Comment: já tentou inserir diretamente numa tabela para testar a trigger?